# Using bzlib in C on macOS Catalina - "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64", "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: c, macos, gcc, bzip2

I am attempting to compile a C program on macOS Catalina. The program will make use of bzip2 decompression. My code includes the line

```
#include <bzlib.h>
```

and I am trying to call the function `BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress`. However, when I run `gcc myfile.c -o myfile.c.o`, I get the following error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I am just using a plain text editor and gcc, no IDEs and no CMake files. I suspect I may need a CMake file for this but I am not really sure how to proceed. Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to link in the bzip library. `gcc myfile.c -o myfile -lbz2`. That command assumes the lib is installed into the standard location. Also, you are compiling a final executable so (by strong convention) it should not have a `.o` suffix.

Comment: Doesn't the error message list the symbol or symbols that are not found?

Comment: @kaylum - I tried compilation again adding -lbz2, -l bz2, and -L /usr/bin -l bz2 to my gcc command. Now I get a bunch of lines saying "warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]", then "fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]." Why is causing that? My code compile fines without the bzip2 decompression part, so I don't think it is an encoding error on my end.

Comment: Can't tell without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Anyway. that's a different question and you should post a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link in the bzip library. `gcc myfile.c -o myfile -lbz2`. That command assumes the lib is installed into the standard location. Also, you are compiling a final executable so (by strong convention) it should not have a .o suffix.

Comment: Looks like I accidentally overwrote my C file with my run.sh script, causing the null warning. For some reason I also have to use sudo to get the linker to work but it is all working now. Thank you for your help, I have accepted the answer!

Comment: I would upvote also but don't have enough reputation yet